# automatically fill text boxes based on a combo box selection in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dropdown

It's been done for MS Access, however I have form in Vb.net for a order form, so when the user selects a value from a drop down box I want their address, postcode, contact numbers etc. to be automatically filled in based on the selection made on the drop down box. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you can start from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx#

Comment: You can populate the textboxes in the indexchanged event of the combobox, i.e. connect to a database based on the combobox selection to get the relevent data and populate the textboxes every time the combobox index changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If Not ComboBox1.Text.Trim() = "Select Supplier" Then

        Using con As New OleDbConnection

            Try

                con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
                     "Data Source = " & My.Settings.dbpath  'your database path here
                con.Open()

                Dim sqlquery_select_suppliers As String

                sqlquery_select_suppliers = "SELECT * FROM Suppliers WHERE SupplierID = '" & ComboBox1.Text.Trim() & "';"

                Dim ds_suppliers As New DataSet

                Dim da_suppliers As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

                da_suppliers = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery_select_suppliers, con)

                da_suppliers.Fill(ds_suppliers, "Suppliers")

                con.Close()

                txt_supplier_name.Text = CStr(ds_suppliers.Tables("Suppliers").Rows(0).Item("SupplierID"))

                'Here you can populate as many textboxes as you like

            Catch Ex as Exeption

            'Exeption message here

            End Try

        End Using

    End If

End Sub
```